# StateListAnimator elevation and ripple effect not working

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I want my Image Button to give it a ripple effect along with 
an elevation. My Image Button already has a 6dp resting elevation, but I am not getting a ripple effect. Below is my code. Can anyone tell what is the error?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/share_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripples_on_touch"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_on_touch"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

**v21/lift_on_touch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="12dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            />
    </item>
</selector>
```

**v21/ripples_on_touch.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#757575"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `android:state_pressed="true"` in your `v21/lift_on_touch.xml` file, make the ImageButton clickable.

Like this

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/share_fab"
    ....
    ....
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_on_touch"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:background="@drawable/ripples_on_touch"`, 
    try `android:foreground="@drawable/ripples_on_touch"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I was able to solve it.

Comment: what was the problem?